# MySql IN Operator on a string

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid IN (SELECT doctors FROM MainPage WHERE Valid=1)
```

users table `uid datatype=INT`, Mainpage table doctors `datatype=text` with value as 1,2,3,4,5

When I am running the above query, it is only resulting 1 row which is for `uid=1`. Is there any other operator OR query change which can retreive me all 5 rows from users table ?

Comment: Does users table has rows for ids 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: what is the output of the subquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function searches for a value in a comma-delimited list. Combine that with a `JOIN` and you should get what you want:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
  JOIN MainPage ON FIND_IN_SET(uid, doctors)
 WHERE Valid = 1;
```

FYI, this is the wrong way to design your tables. Each connection should be defined on a separate row. If it's a many-to-many relationship, that will require a separate table with a composite key.

Comment: @Oggu If it works for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: If i have to achieve the same output on a sql server DB, is there a equivalent operator ?  is FIND_IN_SET() specific to any mysql version ?